# how to iterate from value of parameter request

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm working on a web application that uses Spring MVC and hibernate,

I have this such data,

[image]

on web interface, I send 'MESSAGEID' for request,

'MESSAGEID' is not unique, so I want to iterate the value of parameter request (MESSAGEID) to check the data and just get data that the TRANSACTION='PAYMENT' and SUBTRANSACTION='PROCESSED',

this is my code,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/Detail-BPJS-TK.html")
public ModelAndView listDetailBPJSTK(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ParserConfigurationException, Exception{
    if(!((request.getParameter("MESSAGEID")) == null)){
        String MESSAGEID = request.getParameter("MESSAGEID");
        System.out.println(MESSAGEID);

        DetailBPJS detailbpjs = detailbpjsService.get(MESSAGEID);

        String tes = detailbpjs.getMESSAGEID();
        System.out.println(tes);

        if (!(detailbpjs) == null){
            for (DetailBPJS luna : detailbpjs){
                String trans = detailbpjs.getTRANSACTION();
                String subtr = detailbpjs.getSUBTRANSACTION();

                if(trans == "PAYMENT" && subtr == "PROCESSED"){
                    System.out.println("Yes");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("No");
                }
            }
        }           
    }else{
        System.out.println("Please, check the 'No. Billing' again!!");
        String MESSAGEID = request.getParameter("MESSAGEID");
        System.out.println(MESSAGEID);
        model.addAttribute("errorMessageBPJSTK", "true");
    }

    return listDetailBPJS(model);
}
```

any help will be pleasure :)

Comment: Why iterate and not simply create a query which does the checks for you? Also you should never compare `String` types with `==` always use `equals` for that.

Comment: @M.Deinum what I have supposed to do, I got no clue ~

Answer (score 0):

Try uses request.gerParameterValues(name).

This method returns an array with all values of a specific parameter.